# Refused to display xyz in a frame because it set X-Frame-Options - can I set an allowed domain?

Tags: security, owasp, x-frame-options, response-headers, penetration-testing

I am sorting out a website that will be getting pen-tested soon, we've have been asked to add the X-Frame-Options header to our server configuration. When adding the following header it gives me an error message in the console.log where we are using iframes

-- nginx header --

`add_header 'X-Frame-Options' "SAMEORIGIN";`

-- Error --

`Refused to display 'https://api.domain.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Obviously I understand the security reasons for this header but our website has an iframe that we simply cannot change & it is on a different domain e.g `oldapp.domain.com` rather than `api.domain.com`.
I would have used the `ALLOW-FROM uri` directive to allow from this other domain, but this directive is no longer recommended, is there an alternative to `ALLOW-FROM uri` that will enable me to simply add a domain that can be allowed to display iframe content?

Answer (score 1):

For all browsers except some older ones (like IE) you should use Content-Security-Policy with the frame-ancestors directive instead. With CSP frame-ancestors you can use wildcards *.domain.com or multiple sources "oldapp.domain.com api.domain.com www.domain.com".

X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM only accepts one uri, you will likely have to dynamically set the uri from a list of allowed hostnames based on the incoming request. Alternatively you can set the value to SAMEORIGIN if you don't need to fully support IE and other outdated browsers as X-Frame-Options will be disregarded if CSP frame-ancestors is present.